# Why does `avar=7; exec $avar< <(ls)` make my shell crash

Tags: bash, macos, io-redirection

So I was trying to see if I could have variable numbered output location (the 7). I was wondering what's happening here that's so bad that it causes the whole shell to just break?

The command: `avar=7; exec $avar< <(ls)`

Comment: By the way, newer versions of bash (but not the ancient 3.2 release shipped by Apple) _do_ have a way to perform redirections with a variable used for the FD number.

Comment: that's great, I do have the more updated version and will try this out

Comment: So the problem I was trying to solve in reality was more complicated than I let on for. I was trying to save the output of a forked process into memory so I can later use that for validation. In the end I just made the validation sync while calling the sync function multiple times asynchronously

Comment: You might consider using a coprocess. See the `coproc` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answering The Question As-Asked

`exec 7` tries to *replace* the shell with a program named `7`, just as `exec ls` replaces the shell with a program named `ls`. Either way, the shell exits.

Because redirection syntax is parsed *before* variable expansions take place (subject to specific exemptions added in newer versions of bash than what Apple ships), this does not in any event behave akin to `exec 7< <(ls)`.

---

#### Parameterized Redirections In New Shell Releases

But what if you *do* have a new version of bash? You still don't get to put a variable on the left side of a redirection without using `eval`, but you *do* get automatic allocation of previously-unused file descriptors (and you can use a variable on the right-hand side).

```
# in bash 4.3+ only, allocate a new file descriptor for the process substitution
exec {ls_fd}< <(ls)

# copy that FD to number 7, then close the automatically-assigned one
exec 7<&"$ls_fd" {ls_fd}>&-
```

To perform *exactly* the operation you asked for, you end up using `eval`:

```
avar=7

# again, this requires a newer bash than the stock MacOS one
exec {ls_fd}< <(ls)
printf -v cmd 'exec %d<&"$ls_fd"' "$avar" && eval "$cmd"
exec {ls_fd}>&-
```